# Literature on effect of frequent switching on-off of air conditioner on compressor

Tags: hvac, energy-efficiency, compressor

I tried searching for literature on this using various search terms on google scholar but couldn't get anything substantial. I'm particularly interested in how adversely the AC compressor is affected by frequent switching on-off and how its efficiency is affected. Is there any additional conventional wisdom you could enlighten me with? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you talking about short-cycling by any chance?

Comment: Not quite, I'm thinking of a small project where I use an occupancy sensor hooked to the remote control to turn my AC on/off according to whether someone is in the room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom line; reducing run time will save money and energy. There is nothing wrong with using an occupancy sensor to control whether the A/C can run. If you think about how often a compressor cycles on and off while in use, shutting down when no one is present obviously will REDUCE cycles. As for lack of dehumidification, that is usually only a concern when units are oversized and can not run long enough before reaching temperature set point to remove adequate moisture from the ambient air. Having an unoccupied mode, on the other hand, allows room temperatures to elevate, and thereby necessitating longer recovery run times and actually improving humidity control. Go for it!

Comment: Dear enabler, I may be biased towards accepting your answer as the right one but I don't care :P

Comment: No problem. Good luck on your small project.

Answer (score 1):

My first question is, why are you asking about frequent cycling of the compressor. Do you have a problem with your A/C unit or some great idea you want to try? Frequent cycling of the compressor will drastically shorten it's life. If this is happening with your unit I would have a "hard start kit" installed on your unit along with a short cycle timer. Unless you know how to do this yourself, Call an HVAC person to have these items installed. When I installed HVAC systems I always priced these 2 items into the job and educated the customer as to why I installed them.

Comment: I am thinking of using an occupancy sensor, and switching the AC on/off using its remote control itself based on whether someone is in the room or not. This is a simple Split AC.

Comment: Save your money, Keep the temp where it is set unless you will be out of the room for more than 8-10 hours. If that is not the case there won't be any money saved

Comment: I've seen a similar system in a public building... There, turning AC on started one-hour (I think) countdown. Any movement in the room re-started that countdown. So, if you just left for a bathroom break, AC will stay on, but if the room is empty for more than one hour, AC will turn itself off.

Comment: Your idea may work in a public building with unusual bumps in foot traffic but if it is for a home I would guess it is not a great idea and without longer run times you will not be able to control the humidity. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Air conditioners work best at a steady state. They don’t do well cooling down to temperature and if it is sized right it will take a bit of time to cool down to temperature. If it is run off a motion sensor I would set it for at least a half hour or more. It would be very annoying sitting down reading a book and having the air conditioning continually shut off because you were too still. It takes an air conditioner up to 20 minutes to stabilize pressures which is inefficient. Humidity would go up and down. Compressors should be off for at least 5 minutes to allow the refrigerant to equalize before turning back on again or damage could occur. Hope that helps